# Global event handlers in wxPython (Phoenix)

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython

I'm having a problem trying to handle focus events in wxPython 3, the phoenix fork.

I'm trying to clear the value in a TextCtrl when it's focused if it still has its default value, and then restore that default value on leaving focus if the user hasn't entered a different value.

This is the handler I have:

```
def on_enter(self, event):
    control = wx.Window.FindFocus()
    if control.Id in TEXT_MAPPING.keys():
        if control.Value == TEXT_MAPPING[control.Id]:
            control.SetValue('')
    exit_control = event.GetWindow()
    if exit_control.Id in (TEXT_MAPPING.keys()):
        if not exit_control.GetValue():
            exit_control.SetValue(TEXT_MAPPING[exit_control.Id])
    event.Skip()
```

The handler itself works fine, though it's a little clunky. My issue is that I would like to bind this on a global level, such that whenever any `wx.EVT_SET_FOCUS` event is fired, I can have it be handled by this function.

I found this:

import wx

```
class MyApp(wx.App):
     def FilterEvent(self, evt):
         print evt
         return -1

app = MyApp(redirect=False)
app.SetCallFilterEvent(True)
frm = wx.Frame(None, title='Hello')
frm.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

but I'm confused on how I would pass the event down to the children of `MyApp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is bind focus kill and focus select to functions, like this:

```
self.user_text.Bind(wx.EVT_SET_FOCUS, self.on_focus_username)
self.user_text.Bind(wx.EVT_KILL_FOCUS, self.on_deselect_username)
```

where self is the panel where the TextCtrl "user_text" is located".

The functions might look like this:

```
def on_focus_username(self, event):
    if self.user_text.GetForegroundColour() != wx.BLACK:
        self.user_text.SetForegroundColour(wx.BLACK)
        # Clear text when clicked/focused
        self.user_text.Clear()

def on_deselect_username(self, event):
    if self.user_text.GetLineLength(0) is 0:
        self.user_text.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(192, 192, 192))
        # Put a default message when unclicked/focused away
        self.user_text.SetValue("Enter Username")
```

Hope this helped, if I didn't answer something clearly/correctly let me know.

Comment: I missed the part where you were referencing the actual component on `self`. It works now.

Comment: My issue now is that I would like to do this in a polymorphic way. I don't want to write a separate handler for each TextCtrl.

Comment: Hm, I've never done it where you only have one handler. What you could try, although I'm not sure if it would work, is creating an `on_focus` and `on_deselect` single function that checks an array of booleans that are turned off or on by other functions...
Edit: the booleans would indicate which thing was just left or focused.

Comment: I can't do something like `self.GetComponentByID(event.GetWindow().Id)`?

Comment: However, in your original question, you did say "a Text Ctrl". Even if you have < 10 TextCtrls, this is still one of the cleanest ways because you can customize backgrounds, effects, etcetera.

Comment: You could definitely try that too! I haven't actually used ID getting functions much in my work, but I think that could work if you embed that in the on_whatever_whatever function.

Comment: I don't want to do any sort of customization. I could write individual handlers, but it just seems like I'm duplicating a ton of code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84114/discussion-between-echoace-and-morgan-thrapp).

Comment: Just so you (other viewer that is not me or Morgan) don't have to access chat, the function we found to work is `FindWindowByID`, for everyone else.